# Printing Text inside an HTML table with a background

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to print a simple certificate. The text of the certificate is laid out as an html table.
I am running into a few simple yet maddenning issues.
1) My css changes to the table are completely ignored when I try to print it via chrome.
2) I am not able to figure out a way to print consistently, the text centered in the proper places.
3) I cant figure out a way to transform the entire table and print in a portrait orientation.

My css looks like this:

```
 @media print {
        /* show cover in print */
        .cover {
            display: block;
        }
        .dvCertWrapper {

        }
        .cert {
            width: 1080px!important;
            content: url('../Content/images/certificate.jpg');
            margin-left: -210px;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: right top;
            background-attachment: fixed;
        }
        .certContent {
            display: block;
            margin-top: -680px;
            /*margin-left: 60px;*/
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;

           }
        .startDate {
            display: block;
            font-family: "Century Schoolbook" !important;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-style: normal;
            margin-top: -170px;
            margin-left: -102px;
            position: absolute;
        }
        .endDate {
            display: block;
            font-family: "Century Schoolbook" !important;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-style: normal;
            margin-top: -10px;
            margin-right: -60px;
            position: absolute;
        }
        /* hide other elements in print */
        button {
            display: none;
        }

        .smallText {
            font-size: .8em;
            width: 800px;
        }
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 1800px;
        }
    }
```

My Table Def looks like this:

```
 <table  class="certContent" style="display: block">
        <tbody >
            <tr style="width: 800px !important">
                <td class="smallText">&nbsp;Valid From:&nbsp;{{vendor.dStartDate}}</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="smallText">Valid Till: {{vendor.dEndDate}}&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="4">&nbsp;{{vendor.sBusinessnameLegal}}</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2">{{vendor.iSic1}}</th>
                <th colspan="2">{{vendor.iSic2}}</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">{{vendor.iSic3}}</td>
                <td colspan="2">{{vendor.iSic4}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

No Dice. Previous to this I tried like this:

```
<style>
     html,
     body {
         height: 100%;
         margin: 0;
     }

    .cover {
        /* hidden cover */
        display: none;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    /* fills entire sheet of paper */

    .cert {
        display: block;
        height: 974px;
        width: 1366px;
        background-image: url('../Content/images/certificate.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: right top;
        background-attachment: fixed;
    }
    /* only apply when printing */

    @media print {
        /* show cover in print */
        .cover {
            display: block;
        }
        .cert {
            width: 800px;
            content: url('../Content/images/certificate.jpg');
            margin-left: -160px;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: right top;
            background-attachment: fixed;
        }
        .certContent {
            display: block;
            font-family: "Century Schoolbook" !important;
            font-size: 40px;
            font-style: normal;
            margin-top: -800px;
            margin-left: 60px;
           }
        .leftDate {
            display: block;
            font-family: "Century Schoolbook" !important;
            font-size: 40px;
            font-style: normal;
            margin-top: -10px;
            margin-left: -60px;
        }
        /* hide other elements in print */
        button {
            display: none;
        }
    }
</style>

<button onclick="window.print()">print</button>
<div class="cover">COVERLETTER</div>
<div>
    <div class="cert"></div>
    <div class="certContent">My Business</div>
    <div class="leftDate">01/01/1979</div>
</div>
```

Still not even close.

My background image is sized, 834 x 595  Pixels and I am trying to print in a legal paper.

My finished image should look like this. (I apologize for this graphic, I am not a designer, just flung into a charity project).

[image]

The red boxes depict how I would like to display server data. 
Any ideas or pointers will be much appreciated. Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because printing is handled more by the user's system settings than by the page that is being printed, paper orientation and size sometimes need to be set manually in the print dialog.
I've made this example fit to a sheet of legal paper.
I've also changed the layout from a table into a series of rows, which can have their heights changed.

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
.cover {
  display: none;
  height: 8.5in;
  width: 14in;
}
.cert {
  display: block;
  height: 8.5in;
  width: 14in;
  max-width: 14in;
  max-height: 8.5in;
  position: relative;
}
.cert-img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.cert-content {
  height: calc(100% - 1.6in);
  width: calc(100% - 2.8in);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0.8in 1.4in;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20pt;
  display: flex;
}
.row span,
.row .v-stack {
  flex: 1;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.row-padding {
  height: 0.4in;
}
.val {
  color: red;
}
#valid-to,
#valid-to-value,
#addr-2 {
  text-align: right;
}
#tax-license,
#sig {
  text-align: center;
}
.row-2 {
  margin-bottom: 0.3in;
}
.holder {
  text-align: center;
}
.row-3 {
  margin-bottom: 0.3in;
}
.row-4 table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 18pt;
}
.row-5 {
  height: 2in;
  flex: 1;
}
.row-5 p {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.row-6 {
  margin-bottom: 0.5in;
}
@page {
  margin: 0;
  size: 14in 8.5in landscape;
}
@media print {
  .cover {
    display: block;
  }
  button {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="cover">hello again!</div>
<section class="cert">
  <img class="cert-img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwmVt.png" />
  <div class="cert-content">
    <div class="row row-0 row-padding"></div>
    <div class="row row-1">
      <span id="valid-from">valid from</span>
      <span id="tax-license">tax license <span class="val" id="tax-license-value">000000</span></span>
      <span id="valid-to">valid to</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row row-2">
      <span class="val" id="valid-from-value">date</span>
      <span class="val" id="valid-to-value">date</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row row-3">
      <span class="holder val">holder name</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row row-4">
      <table class="val">
        <tr>
          <td>Allowed to sell</td>
          <td>Allowed to sell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Allowed to sell</td>
          <td>Allowed to sell</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="row row-5">
      <p>The business named above...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row row-6">
      <div class="v-stack" id="addr-1">
        <ul>
          <li>pobox</li>
          <li>addr</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <span class="val" id="sig"><img />signature</span>
      <div class="v-stack" id="addr-2">
        <ul>
          <li>pobox</li>
          <li>addr</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<button onclick="window.print()">Print</button>
```